# Xetex, typewriter fonts and quotes

Tags: xetex, verbatim, typewriter

I use XeTeX with C-language code inside verbatims. The aim is that my students can perform copy/paste from the resulting PDF document into their programming IDE.

Using XeTeX is great because I can use system fonts instead of LaTeX fonts. I wanted to substitute the typewriter font to the system "Courier" font. I used :
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Ligatures=NoCommon}{Courier}

This works great. However, single and double quotes are then replaced by tilted single and double quotes. The result is that it remains in the copy/paste code, that can no longer compile.

Is it possible to ask XeTeX or fontspec or something to use the exact kind of quote used in the verbatim instead of a tilted one ?

Regards ! 
    Mike

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post a compilable code example (MWE) that we can copy and paste to help you.

Comment: please edit typo ``NoCommon]`` not ``NoCommon}``

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem with `\begin{verbatim}`, (on next line) `"Hello"`, and (on next line) `\end{verbatim}` and Mac OS system Courier font (which with `\XeTeXtracingfonts1` one sees it finds in `/System/Library/Fonts/Courier.dfont` with the command `\setmonofont` of your post)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't happen. I tried to compile the minimal document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmonofont[
  Scale=MatchLowercase,
  Ligatures=NoCommon,
]{Courier}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
"Hello" world 'this' is nice
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

with TeX Live from release 2012 to 2019/pretest and the output is always

[image]

If I copy from the PDF file and paste here, I get

```
"Hello" world 'this' is nice
```